# Will Enabling IIS Advanced Logging affect the Server performance

Tags: web-server, iis-7.5, disk-space-utilization

I have an IIS web server and my manager has asked to enable advanced iis logging. Would there be any impact on performance?

Answer (score 2):

> Does enabling advanced logging in IIS need more disk space

OBVIOUSLY collecting more information will use more disc space.

> if yes can you please estimate on how much would be the increase ?

How long is a piece of string? No idea what you collect. Heck, given that I do not know what you collect NOW, I can not even give a multiplier.

> Would there be any impact on performance?

Yes. But that is irrelevant. Relevant is whether there will be any RELEVANT impact on performance. Using twice disc IO is an impact - but going from 1% IO to 2% is not relevant.

And again, as we do not kwow what you collect now and how busy your discs are, how can you even consider expecting us to answer?

Comment: if it is 1GB now, will it be 2GB or something like 5GB or 10GB?